# Rails 5 authenticate_with_http_token, http PUT and Rack Cors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 api where I use authenticate_with_http_token to authorize my requests.

```
def authenticate_token
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
end
```

I have setup Rack::Cors:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :options, :head]
    end
  end
```

This works great for all my GET and POST requests. But when I try to make a PUT request I get an auth error.

The error only happens when I use my local Ionic 2 server, when I use Postman the error does not happen.

That's why I guess it has something do to with the CORS settings.

Can anybody help?

The log when using Ionic is:

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/rides/79?do=setdriver" for ::1 at 2017-02-16 11:06:59 -0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by API::V1::RidesController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Authorization"=>["Token token=14b61d7dc9a2a145a3cfb357f75356e2"]}, "do"=>"setdriver", "id"=>"79", "ride"=>{}}
Filter chain halted as :require_login! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

The log when using POSTMAN is:

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/rides/79?do=setdriver" for ::1 at 2017-02-16 11:26:18 -0200
Processing by API::V1::RidesController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"do"=>"setdriver", "id"=>"79"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["auth_token", "14b61d7dc9a2a145a3cfb357f75356e2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

The parameters looks diferente. But as mentioned I do POST and GET requests from Ionic 2 with the same header.

This is my require_login

```
def require_login!
      if authenticate_token
        return true
      end
      render json: { errors: [ { detail: "Access denied" } ] }, status: 401
    end
```

Comment: Could you paste the headers for both postman and ionic 2 server requests as seen by Rails?

Comment: We see something, but check out the headers itself by ading something like `Rails.logger.debug request.headers` on the require_login! action.

Comment: Also your request_login! action should help a lot as well.

Comment: Based on the logs seems to me that on Ionic you're sending the token as a parameter, not a header. See the postman logs to compare. The headers don't get printed on rails logs.

Comment: Yes, bur wired that my GET and POST requests that run through the same auth process work...

Comment: @tegon, that actually was the problem...one parameter missing in my Ionic request...